# Reset button to original image from filtered image

Tags: ios, objective-c, cifilter

I tried to add filters to my image in image view, when i tried to click on  filter buttons  they are stacking.  Can you help me to create a reset or undo button to go to original image with iam getting original image from camera and camera roll?

```
(IBAction)filter:(id)sender {
CIContext *context=[CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIImage *image =[CIImage imageWithCGImage:imageview.image.CGImage];

CIFilter *filter =[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone"];
[filter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:@1.0f forKey:@"InputIntensity"];

CIImage *result =[filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];


CGImageRef cgImage =[context createCGImage:result fromRect:result.extent];

UIImage *uiImage =[[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:cgImage];
[self.imageview setImage:uiImage];
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50140306/4124168

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filters are stacking because you're modifying the image in the imageview, and then putting that modified image back into the imageview.  You should store your original image in a separate property and always start your modifications from that.  For example, a property like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *originalImage;
```

Then in your method, use the original image instead of the one already in the image view:

```
CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.originalImage.CGImage];
```

Storing data in member variables/properties is also just better practice than storing data in the view.

Comment: thanks for replying i tried this method its showing blank screen can u give example  if u can, it will be a great help

Comment: You will need to assign something to `originalImage` (i.e. whatever you used to populate the imageview to begin with)

Comment: original image coming from camera and camera roll sorry i am new for devloping so how i can assign ?