# Reset CoreImage filter in Swift

Tags: swift, core-image

I am developing simple coreImage filter project in Swift.I am trying to achieve a function like resetting the filtered image back to original. I am using the following code for SepiaTone filter and I am trying to reset the filter using CIColorControls filter.But I am getting fatal crash.I wondering is there any other way to reset the image.

```
        @IBOutlet weak var originalImage: UIImageView!

        @IBAction func SepiaToneFilter(sender: AnyObject) {
        let mySepiaFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
        mySepiaFilter!.setValue(CIImage(image: originalImage.image!), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let myOutputImage : CIImage = mySepiaFilter!.outputImage!            
        originalImage.image = UIImage(CIImage: myOutputImage)
        }

        @IBAction func ResetFilter(sender: AnyObject) {

        let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls") 
        let beginImage = CIImage(image: originalImage.image!)
        currentFilter!.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey
        let output = currentFilter!.outputImage 

        let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output!, fromRect: output!.extent)  **//CreateWrappedSurface() failed for a dataprovider-backed CGImageRef.fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
     (lldb)** 

        let processedImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg)
        originalImage.image = processedImage
        }
```

//Pick Image Process

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    originalImage.image = image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

I am not sure how to run the above function inside my **ResetFilter**(UIButton).

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just hold a reference to the original image? For example:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var originalImage: UIImageView!
    var userImage?:UIImage

    @IBAction func SepiaToneFilter(sender: AnyObject) {
        let mySepiaFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
        if let image = self.userImage {
            mySepiaFilter!.setValue(CIImage(image: image), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            let myOutputImage : CIImage = mySepiaFilter!.outputImage!            
            originalImage.image = UIImage(CIImage: myOutputImage)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func ResetFilter(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let image = self.userImage {
            self.originalImage.image = image
        }

    } 


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
            self.userImage = image
            originalImage.image = image
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.I believe,the code that you posted is already running in my sub-project for testing purpose. I am trying to implement CIfilter project  to my main-project which i am getting the original image from UIImagePickerViewController that grabbing image from photo library. i am not sure how to assign pickerView image as a original image and i also updated my code.please take a look and let me know what you think.Sorry, My bad i forgot to mention about the PickerView.

Comment: I found similar question in the following link [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789547/reset-button-to-original-image-from-filtered-image) .But,I am getting trouble converting the code from Obj-c to Swift...

Comment: I updated my answer. Perhaps you figured it out already, but you can just set a property to be something like "userImage" and set that when you get the image from the `UIImagePickerController`.